# MacBook black screen after 5 seconds

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, screen

Problem occurred when my MacBook was on. Screen suddenly goes black with line of randomly blinking pixels at very top. MacBook is responsive it’s just screen that goes black. Tried restarting NVRAM and SMC. After restarting MacBook, everything goes alright until it fully loads, then after approximately 5 seconds, same story, black screen with random pixels at the top. Closing and opening lid brings back the screen to life for another 5 seconds, then black screen.

In safe mode screen works normally.

Any advice what that could be?

I have just figured out that if I run an app that forces MacBook to switch from Intel UHD to AMD Radeon graphics (I just launch Final Cut Pro) everything works fine. As soon as I quit the app and system goes back to using Intel card I'm getting black screen again (closing and opening lid still makes screen to work for 5 seconds or so). I still don't think that it's a hardware issue as in Safe Mode Intel UHD works just fine.

- 2019 MacBook Pro 16 inch

Comment: What's the exact version of the installed macOS?  Was it cloned or blockcopied etc?

Comment: @da4 it was Big Sur latest version when problem occurred. Now while I've been trying everything, I've updated it to Monterey beta. Everything is exactly the same.

Comment: I saw the same when I had Big Sur installed on the same model for testing, but did not see it recur after I downgraded that device to Catalina.